# Wordpress htaccess index issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've got a wordpress installation, in a root folder unfortunately, and since I have not managed to move the installation to a sub folder, I've attempted to set a different directory index, but I can not acess index.php at all now, and there's a link to it in the site.php. When I try to link site.xx/index.php I just get sent to site.xx/

```
DirectoryIndex site.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^site\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change all references to "index.php" to site.php in this case. If you use a different name for your index. I work for Hostgator and have done this for a fiar amount of customers :)

Comment: Tried that, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Disable Canonical URL Redirection
Description: Disables the "Canonical URL Redirect" features of WordPress 2.3 and above.
Version: 1.0
Author: Mark Jaquith
Author URI: http://markjaquith.com/
*/ 

remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical'); 

?>
```

Put this in a file and put in a folder in the plugin directory of wordpress, activate and you're set.